# Automatic Highlighting Code

Tags: excel, vba, highlight

I got this code from google. I'm wondering how can I make it so that the code doesn't remove previous or new highlighting made by the user.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Clear the color of all the cells
Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
With Target
    ' Highlight the entire row and column that contain the active cell
    .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
    .EntireColumn.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:

```
Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
```